# check if key is present in every segment of size k in array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, index-error

```py
def findxinkindowSize(arr, x, k, n) :

    i = 0
    while i < n :

        j = 0
        
        # Search x in segment
        # starting from index i
        while j < k :
            
            if arr[i + j] == x :
                break
            
            j += 1

        # If loop didn't break
        if j == k :
            return False

        i += k
        
    # If n is a multiple of k   
    if i == n :
        return True

    j = i - k
    
    # Check in last segment if n
    # is not multiple of k.
    while j < n :
        if arr[j] == x :
            break

        j += 1

    if j == n :
        return False

    return True
```

```py
# Driver Code

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    arr = [ 3, 5, 2, 4, 9, 3,
            1, 7, 3, 11, 12, 3 ]
    x, k = 3, 3
    n = len(arr)
    
    if (findxinkindowSize(arr, x, k, n)) :
        print("Yes")
    else :
        print("No")
```

Above code works good for the array of size 3, 6, 9, 12, ... i.e multiples of size of k (segment size), but for the array `arr = [3, 5, 2, 4, 9, 3, 1, 7]` which is of size `8` there is an error in the line `if arr[i + j] == x :` shows out of index.

Is there any better solution for this problem?

Comment: You sure it doesn't give an indentation error?

Comment: There might be an error while typing here now it's updated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple approach using `slicing.`
Iterate through every slice of size `k` and check if `x` is present in that slice or not.

```py
def findxinkindowSize(arr, x, k, n):
    for i in range(0, n, k):
        if x not in arr[i: i+k]:
            return False

    return True
```

This code doesn't give `IndexError`.